# Rearrange equation with nested brackets and trig functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Simple question, but unfortunately haven't been able to find the answer by googling, with my limited math knowledge -

How do I rearrange this, to make y the subject?

Thanks for your help
Brad

---

$$x = \frac{1}{log_.0001 (cos(y))}+0.9999$$

Comment: is log base e or base 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{\log_{0.0001}((\cos(y))}+0.9999$

$\displaystyle x-0.9999=\frac{1}{\log_{0.0001}((\cos(y))}$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{x-0.9999}=\log_{0.0001}(\cos(y))$

$\displaystyle (0.0001)^{\dfrac{1}{x-0.9999}}=\cos(y)$

$\boxed{y=2πn \pm \cos^{-1}\left((10)^{\dfrac{4}{0.9999-x}}\right)}$ for all integer $n$.

Comment: My apologies @Saketh Malyala, I've edited the original post - the log is meant to be base .0001. Thanks for your help